# What is MobileNetv1 depth_multiplier?

Tags: tensorflow

Refering to tensorflow mobilenetv1 model: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9f7a5fa353df0ee2010f8e7a5494ca6b188af8bc/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py#L171

The param depth_multiplier is documented as:

> depth_multiplier: Float multiplier for the depth (number of channels)
>         for all convolution ops. The value must be greater than zero. Typical
>         usage will be to set this value in (0, 1) to reduce the number of
>         parameters or computation cost of the model

But in the ([paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf)), they mention 2 types of multipliers: width multiplier and resolution multiplier, so which one correspond to depth multiplier?

On [Keras](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/application_mobilenet.html), they say that:

> depth_multiplier:  depth multiplier for depthwise convolution (also
>   called the resolution multiplier)

I'm so confused!

Answer (score 7):

As described in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf):

1. The role of the **width multiplier *α*** is to thin a network uniformly at each layer. for a given layer and width multiplier *α*, the number of input channels *M* becomes *αM* and the number of output channels *N* becomes *αN*.
2. The **resolution multiplier *ρ*** is applied to the input image and the internal representation of every layer is subsequently reduced by the same multiplier. In practice we **implicitly** set *ρ* by setting the input resolution.

In the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/9f7a5fa353df0ee2010f8e7a5494ca6b188af8bc/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py#L216):
The **depth_multiplier** is used to reduce the number of channels at each layer. **So the depth_multiplier corresponds the width multiplier *α*.**